# Plugins required for jenkins to plot graphs and to show log/result

Tags: perl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm very new to jenkins. I'm using Jenkins & Robot. Currently, I've written script in perl. Now i'm able to generate `'Xml' file`. And also I've generated `'log.html' and 'result.html'` . 
    I need some interpreter to show these reports on jenkins & also charts as well.
I need your help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install  **HTML publisher plugin**  plugin

Refer [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin)

To display the html in browser

From your job

Select `Add Post-build Action->Publish Html Reports`

Specify the html path in **Html Directory to archieve** section

Specify the html to be displayed in **IndexPages**

Comment: @ Sumesh : Thank you :) That helped me. I installed 'Mail watcher plugin' to send the notification. But i guess this is only for unstable builds. Is there any way how to send the reports after every execution.